# How can I measure the searching time in linkedlists java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I need to measure the searching time for LinkedLists for different values. My solution is not logical, so i don't know if i'm in the right path or not.
This is my solution;

```
    LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        myList.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(myList);
    Random rand = new Random();
    myList.contains(rand.nextInt(myList.size()));
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime());

    LinkedList<Integer> myList2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
        myList2.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(myList2);
    myList.contains(rand.nextInt(myList2.size()));
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime());
```

These are my outputs

38565758048600

38565759163200

Comment: Compare the nanoTime before and after the search and that should tell you how long the search took.

Comment: @AdrianRusso that will tell you how long the JVM took to run the code based on numerous variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can't measure performance like this. Computers are not reliable; not today, and haven't been for decades. OSes pre-empt. the JVM JITs. CPUs have cores. Cores have pipelines and tiered caches. You're hopelessly out of luck; the nanotime between a single `contains` says absolutely not a thing - it's like trying to measure the effect of someone in honolulu peeing in the water by checking the height of the ocean lapping at the pier in Amsterdam. About a billion other factors that are far more impressive in magnitude are involved.

The normal principle for measuring performance is to mark the time, do the thing, and then mark time again. The difference in time? That's how long it took. But you have to run the operation not once; but many many times (and then take the average), and don't actually take the timing seriously until it's run a few times to ensure cache lines and JIT processes have stabilized out. You also need to ensure that the VM hotspot engine won't optimize your entire code away, so you must also actually *use* the result (you are throwing away the `boolean` that `contains` returns; this may lead the hotspot engine to realize that it can just eliminate the entire call, as it couldn't possibly change the list.

This is, in a word, completely and utterly impossible for any java newbie; even a grizzled old veteran is extremely likely to do it wrong, and as it is about timing, it's very hard to 'test' that your timing framework actually works.

Fortunately, you don't have to write it. [It already exists: JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness). You either use that, or a direct competitor of that, or you are getting almost certainly complete lies and fabrications out of your timing code.

Note that the involvement of `Random` is a very bad idea for timing; you want the code you are timing to be as reliable as possible. Thus, do not shuffle the list, and do not ask for a random number. Ask for a specific number every time, or a host of numbers, or duplicate the list, shuffle that, then search for every number - this means that all numbers in the input list are searched for exactly once, but in an arbitrary order.

Comment: I understand that this timing is depending on too many variables. However this task is a must for me, so i'm trying to get the most stable output order as posssible. Thank you for your explanatory answer.

Comment: Okay, so, then, use JMH. What kind of answer is: "Okay, what I am doing is completely meaningless, but I must do it". No you don't. Wanna measure the performance? Download JMH and use it. Don't make excuses.